# Sharing functions between templates in Meteor

Tags: meteor

What if I have two handlebar templates that want to check the return value of the same function? Is there a right way to do this? Obviously I could do this:

```
var say_foo = function() {
  alert('foo');
};

Template.foo.say_foo = say_foo;
Template.bar.say_foo = say_foo;
```

But is there some way to do this directly through the Template object? Since this is JavaScript I can assign a function to any property of any object, but I tried doing:

```
Template.say_foo = function() { alert('foo'); };
```

and of course the templates don't find this function.

Just curious about best practices and the like. Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

<strike>According to the Meteor documentation, the correct way would be to use UI namespace, which would bind to whatever template engine used underneath, instead of using Handlebars, or spacebars directly. Here is the link in documentation. http://docs.meteor.com/#ui_registerhelper</strike>

So for generic function to be accessed from any template use in client.js:

```
UI.registerHelper('stub', function() {
     // code
});
```

#### Update:

Apparently the [docs have changed back to using](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_registerhelper):

```
Template.registerHelper('stub', function() {
     // code
});
```

Then in the the html file use `{{stub}}` to access the variable.

Comment: Thanks, I don't think this existed when I posted the question. In order for this question to remain relevant, it seems appropriate to change this to the accepted answer.

Comment: The docs have now switched back to using `Template.registerHelper`.

Comment: So it's all or nothing? semantically, i would say that if i create a sub-template i should inherit all the parent template's functions

Comment: doc location has changed to :http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Template-registerHelper

Answer (score 17):

I think a better version would be (if you use Handlebars, which is the default) :

```
Template.registerHelper('my_helper', function() {
     // code
});
```

You can call this from any template using {{my_helper}} !

Hope it helps :)

Comment: The correct way is using UI.registerHelper, according to the meteor docs. Please see my answer below.

Comment: @srinivas: that "correct way" changed throughout Meteor's history, it was Handlebars, then UI, now Template. Original outdated answers should be edited instead of posting new ones that create a hard-to-read list. I've updated this one accordingly, since is the first and most upvoted

Comment: @BogdanD For sharing functions between templates, I think we still have to register it as a function in UI, other wise you won't be able to share the function between templates. Yes I could have put the answer in a comment though, but I thought that would be hard to find out.

Comment: @srinivas, I meant edit the answer, not comment (my edit to this answer is pending approval, that's why is not in the answer already). About UI - it's now deprecated, Template replaced it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I came up with to solve the problem. This is done using CoffeeScript. If you're not using CoffeeScript, you can convert it to JavaScript [here](http://js2coffee.org/#coffee2js).

First, define the `extendTemplate` function:

```coffeescript
extendTemplate = (template, mixin) ->
  helpers = ({name, method} for name, method of mixin when name isnt "events")
  template[obj.name] = obj.method for obj in helpers

  if mixin.events?
    template.events?.call(template, mixin.events)

  template
```

Then, declare an object with helpers and events (mine is called `loginMixin`) that you'd like to share across multiple templates:

```coffeescript
loginMixin =
  merge_with_email: ->
    return Session.get 'account_merge__merge_with_email'

  events:
    'click button#merge_login': (event, template) ->

      email = $(template.find('#email')).val()
      password = $(template.find('#password')).val()

      Meteor.loginWithPassword email, password, (error)->
        if error
          console.error "Failed to login."

      return false
```

Then, after declaring your templates, you can extend them with the above mixin. With the following code, I'm extending my `register` and `login` templates:

```coffeescript
extendTemplate Template.register, loginMixin
extendTemplate Template.login, loginMixin
```

Lastly, here's how my `login.html` can look like:

```html
<template name="login">
    <div class="alert">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">×</a>
        <h4 class="alert-heading">Merge accounts</h4>
        <form id="register_form" class="form-inline" action="#">
            <p class="help-block">Please login with {{merge_with_email}}.</p>
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input id="email" type="text" class="input-medium" />
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input id="password" type="password" class="input-medium" />
            <button class="btn" id="merge_login">Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>
```

Since I extended my `register` template as well, `register.html` can also use `{{merge_with_email}}` and have the `click` event of the `merge_login` button handled as well.

Comment: Really cool but how do you run `Template.instance()` to get the template inside a helper?

Answer (score 2):

With Meteor 1.0 here now, this seems to have changed. After some digging, I found that you can now use the following to reuse code between helpers:

https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_registerhelper

```
Template.registerHelper("checkedIf",function(value){
  return (value)? "checked":"";
});
```

This makes it available in all helpers!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand what you're asking, but I don't see anything wrong with what you're doing - you assigned a function to variable in order to reuse it multiple times.

If it's a matter of wanting to type less or having, say, 20 different templates reuse it rather than 2, you could do something like this:

```
var templates = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'barz', 'bliz', blaz'];
for (var i=0; i < templates.length; i++) { 
    Template[templates[i]].say_foo = say_foo;
}
```

But IMO this is less readable, and there's no real need to do it.

EDIT - Better solution

Just realized why you might want to do this - to make sure every Template has the `say_foo` attribute so you have to worry about adding it manually every time you create a new template, you could do this:

```
for (var t in Template)
    Template[t].say_foo = say_foo;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current approach should work. A somewhat shorter version would be:

```
Template.foo.say_foo = 
Template.bar.say_foo = function() { alert('foo'); };
```

Answer (score 0):

After messing with  Gezim's excellent answer I realized in Meteor 1.3+ you can simply run:

```
Template.register.helpers(MyMixin.helpers);
Template.register.events(MyMixin.helpers);
```

But if you want an extendTemplate function:

```
// Note: above code is probably simpler.

function extendTemplate(template, mixin) {
  if (mixin.helpers && template.helpers) {
    template.helpers(mixin.helpers);
  }
  if (mixin.events && template.events) {
    template.events(mixin.events);
  }
  return template;
};

extendTemplate(Template.register, {
  events: { ... },
  helpers: { ... },
});
```