# Using inheritance in meteor.js

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, inheritance, meteor

I've been hoping to use inheritance in Meteor, but I couldn't find anything about it in the documentation or on Stack Overflow.

Is it possible to have templates inheriting properties and methods from another abstract template, or class?

Comment: I created [a package](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/view)  called `view` for meteor. I use it to wrap meteor views with a backbone like view class. Maybe you'll find some ideas to start with in there.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think the short answer is no, but here's a longer answer:

One thing I've done to share functionality among templates is to define an object of helpers, and then assign it to multiple templates, like so:

```
var helpers = {
    displayName: function() {
        return Meteor.user().profile.name;
    },
};

Template.header.helpers(helpers);
Template.content.helpers(helpers);

var events = {
    'click #me': function(event, template) {
        // handle event
    },
    'click #you': function(event, template) {
        // handle event
    },
};

Template.header.events(events);
Template.content.events(events);
```

It's not inheritance, exactly, but it does enable you to share functionality between templates.

If you want all templates to have access to a helper, you can define a global helper like so (see https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Handlebars):

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('displayName',function(){return Meteor.user().profile.name;});
```

Comment: This is quite useful. Thanks. How about extending the events? Any ideas there?

Comment: @Pilgrim I added some examples for events too.

Comment: Why not just use `Handlebars.registerHelper`? Another thing I do is have an `index` template, within which all the others are added - that allows me to add events to `Template.index.events` and it applies over the whole page

Comment: @Swadq That index template is a cool technique.  As for why not to use Handlebars.registerHelper, it's for the same reason that Meteor has template-specific helpers in the first place, not just global helpers: it's just generally better not to pollute the global Handlebars namespace with a set of methods that might only apply to a couple of templates.

Answer (score 2):

I've answered this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15601657/32495). While the solution doesn't use `inheritance`, it allow you to share events and helpers across templates with ease.

In a nutshell, I define an `extendTemplate` function which takes in a template and an object with helpers and events as arguments:

```
extendTemplate = (template, mixin) ->
  helpers = ({name, method} for name, method of mixin when name isnt "events")
  template[obj.name] = obj.method for obj in helpers

  if mixin.events?
    template.events?.call(template, mixin.events)

  template
```

For more details and an example see my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15601657/32495).

Comment: Best answer, in OOP it's recommended you use "composition over inheritance" and this answer favors the former.

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I needed the same functionality in my app so I've decided to create my own package that will do that job out of the box. Although it's still work in progress, you can give it a go.

Basically, the entire method is as follows:

```
// Defines new method /extend
Template.prototype.copyAs = function (newTemplateName) {
    var self = this;

    // Creating new mirror template
    // Copying old template render method to keep its template
    var newTemplate = Template.__define__(newTemplateName, self.__render);
    newTemplate.__initView = self.__initView;

    // Copying helpers
    for (var h in self) {
        if (self.hasOwnProperty(h) && (h.slice(0, 2) !== "__")) {
            newTemplate[h] = self[h];
        }
    }

    // Copying events
    newTemplate.__eventMaps = self.__eventMaps;

    // Assignment
    Template[newTemplateName] = newTemplate;
};
```

In your new template (new_template.js) in which you want to extend your abstract one, write following:

```
// this copies your abstract template to your new one
Template.<your_abstract_template_name>.copyAs('<your_new_template_name>');
```

Now, you can simply either overwrite your helpers or events (in my case it's `photos` helper), by doing following:

```
Template.<your_new_template_name>.photos = function () {
    return [];
};
```

Your  will refer to overwritten helper methods and to abstract ones that are not overwritten.

Note that HTML file for new template is not necessary as we refer to abstract one all the time.

Source code is available on Github [here](https://github.com/grabbou/meteor-template-extend)!