# Two ways to define helpers in Meteor

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js, meteor-helper

**EDIT: This is no longer relevant in Meteor 1.0. The first syntax has been deprecated, and only the second is supported.**

It seems that there are two ways to define what are apparently called helpers in Meteor:

```
Template.foo.helper1 = function() { ... }
```

Other way:

```
Template.foo.helpers({
  helper2: function() { ... }
});
```

Is there any semantic or usage difference between the two? The only restriction I can see is that the first usage can't use reserved keywords. I'm wondering if the distinction arose only for historical reasons or if there is something else.

Answer (score 9):

According to http://docs.meteor.com/#template_helpers they are equivalent aside from the syntax, and the `Template.myTemplate.foo` syntax will not work for reserved template names.

The nice thing about using a dictionary passed to `Template.myTemplate.helpers` is that you can reuse it across multiple templates.

```
    var reusableHelpers = { stuff: function() { return "stuff"; } };
    Template.foo.helpers( reusableHelpers );
    Template.bar.helpers( reusableHelpers );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for are details in regards to handlebars, found here:

http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html

Answer (score 0):

As answered there: [Sharing functions between templates in Meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220488/sharing-functions-between-templates-in-meteor/26713268#26713268), with Meteor 1.0 here now, this seems to have changed. After some digging, I found that you can now use the following to reuse code between helpers:

https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_registerhelper

```
Template.registerHelper("checkedIf",function(value){
  return value?"checked":"";
});
```

This makes it available in all helpers!