# What is Template.myTemplate.helpers(helpers) for and why should I use it?

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

In Meteor, if the below is my HTML,

```
   <template name="myTemplate">
The value is {{value}}
</template>
```

I can define the value in two ways

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers
    value: ->
        'insideHelper1'

Template.myTemplate.value =
    'outsideHelper1'
```

The first way is using helpers as documented here (http://docs.meteor.com/#template_helpers) whereas the second way is using the Live Template examples as defined here (http://docs.meteor.com/#livehtmltemplates)

Just wondering, what is the difference between the two and when should I use one over the other?

Comment: There is no difference. I always use the first way because the structure of the helper will be the same as on the event callbacks and easy to seperate from created, destroyed and rendered callback. This keeps for me more readability. Your outsideHelper is just a shorthand form of the insideHelper.

Comment: The same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17099929/two-ways-to-define-helpers-in-meteor I always use the first way too, because if you later change the template name, you only need to change the name in one place for all the helpers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're exactly the same.

If you use `.helpers`, it actually just adds it to `Template.`.

It depends on your coding style. You may prefer to use `.helpers` since it makes cleaner code if you have many helpers on the same template.

One small technically way they're different is `Template.helpers` adds the helpers to your Meteor app when your Meteor app starts up, whereas using the `Template.helpername` adds it before. So if you need to overwrite any helpers, you could use the `.helpers` method. The one that runs last will have the active helper.